# Skiasharp on Xamarin forms: SKCodec.Create returns null

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I am following SKiaSharps example from the github repo. 
In my own code, I do the following:

```
    var stream = new SKManagedStream(sourceStream);
    var srcImage = SKBitmap.Decode(stream);<---This line
```

sourceStream is System.IO.MemoryStream retrieved from MediaFile's GetStream() like this:

```
    var media = await DependencyService.Get<IShare>().PickImage();
    _imageSource = media.GetStream();
    canvas.InvalidateSurface();
```

The Market code in the first snippet throws exception, SKCodec cannot be null.

I have spent about a  week on this issue, but no avail. 
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: first hit in Google - https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/issues/131

Comment: Thanks. I did. I forgot to mention that in my post. That did not solve the issue.Also, Xamarin forms does not have System Bitmap object.